# Non-english character getting changed to "." character in linux

Tags: python, django, unicode, localization, character-encoding

I am trying to create a "Language File" for adding localization to my Django application.

The problem is that when the translate text has some non-english characters then they get replaced by a "." character and Django complains this giving an error.

For eg:

```
English                        German 
Change Password                Passwort ändern
```

So here `ä` gets replaced by `.`

I don't understand why am I not able to paste this text inside my text file. I am able to paste it on the terminal but not inside the file when I open it through `vi`

I am using `linux 2.6.32` on an embedded device.

The error message obtained in Django while preparing the language file is:

```
locale/de/LC_MESSAGES/django.po:472:70: invalid multibyte sequence
```

I have no idea why its happening like this. Can anybody suggest some solution?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What error does Django give you? Chances are it doesn't know what encoding the translation is in.

Comment: @Thomas: updated the question with the error message obtained in Django

Comment: @Thomas: executing "cat django.po" show the contents correctly i.e. without replacing "ä" with "."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, I solved my problem. I was getting the error invalid multibyte sequence because the problem was that the .po wasn't encoded properly.

I could confirm this by executing the following command:

```
file -i django.po
```

It gave the output that the encoding type of the file was `ISO-8859-1`

So, I converted the file to "UTF-8" using the following command:

```
iconv --from-code=ISO-8859-1 --to-code=UTF-8 django.po > django_utf8.po
```

Then replaced the old django.po file with the newly generated one and "makemessages" and "compilemessages" worked like a charm.

Thank you everybody above for your answer.

Hope this helps somebody in the future!

Comment: Glad you fixed it. To be picky: ISO-8859-1 is a character encoding, not a mime type.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have some mismatch in encodings. Nowadays, Linux generally uses utf-8, but you may still have legacy iso-8859-*n* set somewhere and this would cause problems. Also django needs to know as which encoding to interpret the file.

- Vim has options `encoding` (that specifies encoding it uses internally and default for the other two), `fileencoding` (that specifies encoding to read and write *particular* file in (per-buffer)) and `termencoding` (that specifies encoding used to display on terminal; it's not used in the graphical version). It allows to specify `fileencoding` for file to open by adding `++enc=` flag to the `:edit` command. So you open the file e.g. like `:e ++enc=utf-8 file.txt`. Try various combinations until the character shows up correctly and vim does not complain that something can't be converted. Than you'll know what encoding you are using.
- In python by default only ascii characters are translated between byte strings (`str`) and unicode (`unicode`) strings. If you want to open a file in different encoding and iterpret the strings, you have to open it with explicit encoding the `codecs` package.

If it's open somewhere in django, you'll have to find out how to tell it the encoding.

Comment: I am connecting to my device through putty. Now when I paste the translated text "Passwort ändern" into the terminal it shows exactly as it should... but when I open "vi" and paste the contents inside it, then the "ä" character in "Passwort ändern" gets replaced by "." (Dot character).. I tried changing settings of putty to UTF-8.. but still didn't work for vi.. it worked for the terminal's display without changing the setting for putty... Any idea where should i change the setting...

Comment: One more update; when I execute "cat django.po", it shows the correct text display i.e. "Passwort ändern" and not "Passwort .ndern".. I don't understand what does this mean.. Is it a problem with Django.. I have updated the question with the error message.